# Features considered by ExtraTreeRegressor of Scikit Learn to construct Random Forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I came across [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_multioutput.html#example-ensemble-plot-forest-multioutput-py) which involves completion of face for the test data set. Here, a value of `32` for `max_features` is passed to the `ExtraTreesRegressor()` function. I learnt that decision trees are constructed, which selects random features from the input data set. For the example from the above link, images are used as train and test data set. [This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29) describes various types of image features. Now I am not able to understand which features dose `sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreeRegressor` look for or extract from the image data set provided as input to construct the random forest. Also, how is it determined that a value of `32` is optimum for `max_features`. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random forests do not do feature extraction. They use the features in the dataset given to them, which in this example are just pixel intensities from the Olivetti faces dataset.

The `max_features` parameter to an [`ExtraTreesRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.html) determines "the number of features to consider when looking for the best split" (inside the [decision tree learning algorithm](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart) employed by the forest).

The value 32 was probably determined empirically.

Answer (score 6):

The features used here are the raw pixel values. As the images in the dataset are aligned and quite similar, that seems to be enough for the task.

Answer (score 2):

As others said: in this naive example there is no feature extraction: the extra trees just use the raw pixels as features.

In a more realistic computer vision setting it is very likely that performing hand tuned feature extraction will lead to more interesting models. The kind of features to extract depends on the computer vision task you want to achieve. Read the literature or examples from the OpenCV library to know the state of the art in computer vision (leaving neural net-based representation learning aside as bleeding edge research for now).

The 32 value for the parameter can be randomized searched. See this example from the master branch for an example:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/randomized_search.html#example-randomized-search-py